# Daylight Savings Time ignored using in_time_zone Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a frustrating issue that I can't seem to narrow down. I have searched many similar articles but they are not close enough to my issue to resolve. I am trying to pull a time from the database and display it in more than one time zone. My Rails app is using UTC as default. Here is what I'm doing:

On the create action I take the string of time which will be saved in the time column in my DB:

```
params[:schedule][:start] = "09:00"
Time.zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
@schedule.start = Time.zone.parse(params[:schedule][:start])
```

The above formats the time as it is supposed to:

```
2016-04-12 09:00:00 -0500
```

This is saved in the DB as:

```
2000-01-01 14:00:00
```

This has no time offset which is fine since I know it's in UTC. The problem happens when I go to display the time:

```
@schedule.start.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)")
```

This returns:

```
Sat, 01 Jan 2000 08:00:00 CST -06:00
```

Now, since this is a time column, I don't care about the date. I plan on formatting the value to only show the time. However, it is showing CST when it is currently CDT.

I can't figure out why this is happening. As I said I am not setting the Time Zone anywhere in my application.rb or anywhere else and I only set the Time zone on the create action which should be fine when moving to a new action.

Any help on clarifying this would be awesome!

This seems to be because when the time is stored it is stored with the date in the year 2000-01-01 which seems to be why it is using CST. How can I ignore the date when converting it to a particular timezone or will I need to change the column type to DateTime to get this to work properly?

Comment: Running into this same issue. Essentially `in_time_zone` takes into account the Date of the provided `DateTime` and whether that Time Zone was in Daylight Savings at the Date and Time of the provided `DateTime`. This is insanely confusing. Because I'm currently not in Daylight Savings time, I would want to view this information in my current Time Zone (or offset), not in the Time Zone (or offset) that was at the `DateTime` in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showing CST simply because the time is read from the database **including the stored date**, i.e. it's read as 09:00 of Jan 1st 2000.

I guess you'd have to parse the time upon reading the attribute back. You can use a helper method in your model, for example:

```
# schedule model
def start_in_zone(zone)
  self.start.strftime("%H:%M").in_time_zone(zone)
end
```

This will take only the hours and minutes part of the stored time and parse it in the given time zone with the date set to today. See this example:

```
"Sat, 01 Jan 2000 08:00:00".to_time.
     strftime("%H:%M").
     in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)")
# => Tue, 12 Apr 2016 08:00:00 CDT -05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it matters whether it's CST or CDT means you *do,* on some level, care about the date. While I'm not familiar with the exact rules of Daylight Savings in that region, I do know that Jan 1 is the middle of winter and will definitely not be on Daylight Savings time.

Add the relevant date into your `@schedule` before putting it into a time zone, and it should fix the problem.